# C++20's std::views::filter not filtering the view correctly

Tags: c++, filter, g++, c++20, std-ranges

I was writing a simple C++ program that generates a list of random integer values from a normal distribution, then takes first N generated items and filters them so that their absolute value is greater than 42. The code i wrote is the following:

```
int main() {
//convenience
    namespace rng = std::ranges;
    namespace view = std::views;
//random generation boilerplate
    std::random_device r;
    std::mt19937 gen(r());
    std::normal_distribution<float> taps(-4, 15);
 //the filtering   
    for (const auto& value : view::repeat(0)
        | view::transform([&taps, &gen](auto _) { return std::round(taps(gen)); })
        | view::take(1005)
        | view::filter([](auto val) { return (val < -42 || val > 42); }))
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if i remove the `view::filter` line, the sequence seems to be perfectly normal and there are about 3 or so values that satisfy the condition. However, when the filter is applied, the output seems to be some random trash, like `-12 -8 -14 2 -4 -11 -38`. How does that make any sense? These numbers don't even satisfy the filtering condition. Any help is appreciated.

notes: 
compiled with `g++ -o test main.cpp -std=c++2b`, both on Windows and Linux. 
 If i replace views::repeat(0) with views::iota(0) and compile with `-std=c++20`, the output is the same - some random garbage. 
 Also, if someone suggests the better way to generate list from lambda, I would appreciate this a lot.

Comment: These are "lazy" view, so your `transform` to random is done each time you deference that iterator.

Comment: Oh, thanks, didn't consider that. I added output to transform function, and it outputted for each take and successful filter.

Comment: Related question: [Why C++ ranges "transform -> filter" calls transform twice for values that match the filter's predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199664/why-c-ranges-transform-filter-calls-transform-twice-for-values-that-match)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`std::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) requires the function object to be [`regular_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable), which means repeated calls must produce the same value; otherwise the behavior is undefined.

In range-v3 there are `views::generate` and `views::generate_n` for generating a sequence from repeated function calls, but it's not included in the standard library (yet).

For now, it might be easier to use a non-lazy algorithm.

```
std::vector<int> values;
std::ranges::generate_n(std::back_inserter(values), 1005,
    [&taps, &gen] { return std::round(taps(gen)); });

for (const auto& value : values
    | view::filter([](auto val) { return (val < -42 || val > 42); }))
{
    std::cout << value << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As a supplement to the answer, in C++23 you can easily construct a random number generator view using [`std::generator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator), which eliminates the need for an extra container to store random numbers

```
#include <generator>

std::generator<int> generate(auto gen) {
  for (;;)
    co_yield gen();
}
```

then you can use it like

```
auto gen = [] {
  static std::random_device r;
  static std::mt19937 gen(r());
  static std::normal_distribution<float> taps(-4, 15);
  return taps(gen);
};

for (const auto& value : generate(gen)
    | view::take(1005)
    | view::filter([](auto val) { return (val < -42 || val > 42); }))
{
   // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EYY88dcbx) (use the implementation provided by [P2502](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2502r2.pdf))